# Change arrow position React for Swiper.js

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, sass, swiper.js

I get imgages of cats by API, and display them on screen for slider using Swiper.js, however I am not sure how to make these arrows to be outside of one block, which contains `cat-image`, `cat-name` (in the future, there is going to be some additional info).

Here is my APP.tsx

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.scss';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper/modules';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCats = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?limit=10&has_breeds=1&api_key=*MY API KEY*`,
        );
        setData(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    fetchCats();
  }, []);

  return (
    <main className="main">
      <Swiper navigation={true} modules={[Navigation]} slidesPerView={1} className="cat mySwipper">
        {data.map((item) => (
          <SwiperSlide className="cat-slider" key={item.id}>
            <div className="cat-image">
              <img src={item.url} />
            </div>
            <div className="cat-info">
              <h1>{item.breeds[0].name}</h1>
            </div>
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here is my SCSS file:

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#root {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.main {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background-color: orange;
}

.cat {
  height: 100vh;

  &-slider {
    max-width: 100%;

    display: flex !important;
  }
  &-image {
    width: 70%;
    img {
      object-fit: cover;
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  &-info {
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
  }
}
```

I managed to move them only by using margins for every arrow with `::after` using `!important`, but as far as I know, this is not welcome in such developments. I suppose it would be much better if there is any way to make them outside of my block of sliders.